# ajax get null value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code can get data in Chrome console

but cant get data in my program

code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var theme = '';
    var source = [];
    var rsps = '';

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/RoleMenus")',
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                rsps = response;
                source = eval(response);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStattus,errorThrown) {
                $('#jqxErrorMsg').html(errorThrown);
            }
        });

        for(var src in source) {
            if (src.items.legth > 0) {
                src.expanded = true;
            }
        }

        // Create jqxTree
        $('#jqxTree').jqxTree({ source: source, theme: theme});
        $('#jqxTree').bind('select', function (event) {
                var args = event.args;
                var item = $('#jqxTree').jqxTree('getItem', args.element);

                for (var menu in source[0]) {
                    if (item.label == menu.label) {
                        window.location = menu.actionUrl;
                        //break;
                    }
        }
            });
    });
```

=====update=====
the response is right, if i move

```
 // Create jqxTree
 $('#jqxTree').jqxTree({ source: source, theme: theme});
```

into `success: function(response, status, xhr) {}`

the menu shows correctly

but the `source` variable still has no value outside

=====solved====

```
 for (var menu in source[0])
```

should be

```
for (int i=0;i<source[0].length;i++)
```

Comment: Typo here `url:"@Url.Content("~/Home/RoleMenus")"` to `url:"@Url.Content('~/Home/RoleMenus')"`

Comment: Can you post the content of `response`. Also, you have a typo, `legth` should be `length`.

Comment: @ubercooluk That's not a typo, he's using Razor templating, so that's perfectly valid. I've amended it to save confusion though.

Comment: ubercooluk, your wrong...the @Url.Content is server side so it's correct

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i think the response content is right see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax call is async so source variable may not be initialized yet. Try putting

```
        for(var src in source) {
            if (src.items.legth > 0) {
                src.expanded = true;
            }
        }

        // Create jqxTree
        $('#jqxTree').jqxTree({ source: source, theme: theme});
```

in the succes function.

Comment: can i put $('#jqxTree').bind('select', function (event) {}); in the success function????

Comment: the problem is: my `bind` function can't get data outside, but seems i can't bind this function in success function

Comment: Can you put your bind function in the success block?